# Extract fields and values from string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the field name and the value.From a string containing fields and values like the following one:

```
/location=(7966, 8580, 1) /station=NY /comment=Protein RadB n=1 Tax=M (SB / ATCC) RepID=A6USB2_METV
```

- Each string can contain a different number of fields
- The field names will always be enclosed between '/' and '='
- The values can contain '/' and whitespace but not '='

The expected result is something like:

```
['location','(7966, 8580, 1)','station','NY','comment','Protein RadB n=1 Tax=M (SB / ATCC) RepID=A6USB2_METV']
```

So far I've been able to extract the field names using:

```
>> re.findall(r"\/([a-z]*?)\=",string)
['location', 'station', 'comment']
```

And I've tried to use negative `?!` without success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you change the "/" separator at "(SB / ATCC)" to something like "|" ? So we can split("/") and work with the data

Comment: if you do the change @dot.Py mentioned something like `\=(.*?)\/` might do the trick

Comment: I can't. At first I tried with simple split("/") until I discovered some field values like the one (XX / YY / ZZ) that's when I thought regex could do the trick.

Comment: try `s.replace(" / ", " | ")` and `s.split("/")`

Comment: why not just .split('//')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the re.split()

```
>>> string
'/location=(7966, 8580, 1) /station=NY /comment=Protein RadB n=1 Tax=M (SB / ATCC) RepID=A6USB2_METV'
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\s*/([a-z]+)=')
>>> pattern.split(string)[1:]
['location', '(7966, 8580, 1)', 'station', 'NY', 'comment', 'Protein RadB n=1 Tax=M (SB / ATCC) RepID=A6USB2_METV']
```

re.split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)

Split string by the occurrences of pattern. If capturing **parentheses** are used in pattern, then the text of **all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list**.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) to first split the "key=value" pairs, then regular [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) splitting by the first occurrence of `=`:

```
>>> dict(item.split("=", 1) for item in re.split(r"\s*/(?=[a-z]*?\=)", s)[1:])
{
  'comment': 'Protein RadB n=1 Tax=M (SB / ATCC) RepID=A6USB2_METV', 
  'station': 'NY', 
  'location': '(7966, 8580, 1)' 
}
```